# Top-down vs Bottom-up Approach

Tags: web-services, bottom-up, top-down

I understand the difference between the two approaches of web Development. But are there any situations when a specific approach is advantageous over the other ? And downside of one over the other ?

I read this in an article: In top-down, if we make changes in WSDL , we need to changes the JAVA classes. While in bottom-up, any changes made in JAVA classes are taken care of during the build.

Any other ?

Answer (score 0):

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/pdf/spring-ws-reference.pdf

I found this document very useful in understanding why Top-Down approach is widely used.

Comment: This is indeed a very interesting article . Thanks !